# Copy a formula in Excel from one worksheet to another and have worksheet name in formula update

Tags: excel, copy, formula, excel-2013

I have an Excel workbook with each months accounting sheet tabs, Jan > Dec. In opening debits, I have a formula:

```
=IF(JAN!D31>0,JAN!D31,JAN!-D31)
```

which says, if `D31` is greater than zero, then copy that value to `G4` (opening debits); if `D31` is 0 or a minus, then change the value for `G4` to show a plus so it adds to my `Debits` column for a new monthly total.

I can copy the formula to each month @ G4, but since I have 12 months of worksheets, I am currently having to manually edit each months G4 to change the month, i.e. `=IF(JAN!D37>0,JAN!D37,-JAN!D37)` to, for instance, `=IF(FEB!D37>0,FEB!D37,-FEB!D37)`. I want the month to change but not the cell reference.

Is there a way to copy the formula to Feb through December and have the month portion change appropriately? I can supply a screenshot.

I tried Microsoft Community for answers but they were not able to come up with anything. Otherwise, I have nothing else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Home me that you want every month to use line 31 as a criterion ... In this case, try clicking the cursor about the reference cell "jan! D31" and change the text to "jan! D $ 31" inserting a $ between "D" and "31". After that copy and paste or drag the formula.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The key to solve this is the function `INDIRECT`. First you need a list of the month names / sheet names in some column. Lets say those month names are in column H, rows 4, 5, 6, ... . In G4, replace

```
  =IF(JAN!D37>0,JAN!D37,-JAN!D37)
```

by

```
  =IF(INDIRECT(H4) & "!D37">0,INDIRECT(H4) & "!D37",-INDIRECT(H4)  & "!D37")
```

Now, when you copy-fill down the formula of column G, H4 will be automatically replaced by H5, H6, ..., and each new formula refers to the correct month.

If you only want a single place to change the month name (keeping the formula in G4), this will work too, just edit the month name in H4.

Comment: Doc Brown:   didn't work.  I get a #REF indidation in G4.  Is there any way I can send you a screen sho t?  also, My current formulas have a $D$37 design.

Comment: @Ken26: just edit the question and make it less vague - currently, it leaves a lot of guessing in which sheet and which cell you have which formula. You can add images to your question,, didn't you notice?